# Managed Package triggers not working in lightning

Tags: trigger, lightning, salesforce-id

I have a managed package which copies custom fields from OpportunityLineItem to QuoteLineItem when created. That is working perfectly in classic but not working salesforce Lightning.
Please suggest. Do I have to make any changes when moving from classic to lightning?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Triggers fire regardless of Lightning or Classic. Do you perhaps have some logic in your triggers? Can you share relevant parts of your code?

Comment: Please try to be more specific in your question so we can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apex is not affected by the UI used.